# Creating XML in C# using templates with placeholders

Tags: c#, xml

I have various classes that I need to write to XML for distribution to client systems.

I know the obvious way to convert a class in c# is to serialize. Ideally I would do this - however my boss wants me to use some sort of template system.

So I would have a template (basic example) like the following and replace the tags as required.

```
<Advert>
<Title>{Title}</Title>
<Description>{Description}</Description>
[etc etc etc etc]
</Advert>
```

I really don't want to do it this way, but that's life :) Does anyone have good suggestions on how to do this? Libraries etc? Hoping there is something a bit more powerful then string replace (etc) - but got a feeling that's the way it may go!

**EDIT:**

What I should have stated is, the idea is to be able to tweak the XML template without having to do a rebuild of the application.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
                 {
                    {"Title", "Hello"}, 
                    {"Description", "Descr1"}
                 };
string xml = "<Advert><Title>{Title}</Title><Description>{Description}</Description></Advert>";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(xml, @"\{(.+?)\}", m => parameters[m.Groups[1].Value]);
```

Comment: Simple and clever

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx). If I'm reading your question right, you could do:

```
// Set these however you want
string title = "{Title}"
string description = "{Description}"

XDocument xml = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Advert",
        new XElement("Title", title),
        new XElement("Description", description)
        ... ));
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that the idea is to be able to change the XML format without having to rebuild the application.

Comment: Got it. There are various methods in the XDocument and XElement classes, which allow you to alter existing elements, or add new elements. I'll leave it up to you as to whether they work for your application.